# Java With SQL Mapper

Tags: java, sql

Ok this is what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have several views each view can have aliases and such like that and each view goes back to either another or view or a table. What I want to do is trace a specific field from it's view all the way down to the source.
For example if I have this sql statement:

```
replace view blah
Select
t.acct_nmbr as I_account,
sum (t.num1+p.location) as location,
from blahTable as t 
left outer join blahTable2 p
on t.acct_nmbr=p.acct_nmbr;
```

This is a very simple case but what I want it is if I say trace(i_account) I will get the following hierarchy:

```
I_account --> blahTable ---> acct_nmbr
```

Or if I want location I would get the following:

```
location --> sum (t.num1+p.location)-->blahTable --> num1
------------------------------------------------>blahTable2 --> location
```

You can see that adding more and more it can get complicated to trace this especially if there is multiple joins and select and derived tables as well. I'm currently trying to code this from scratch but I wasn't sure if there was something out there already that does this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an interesting concept.  Ordinarily, I'd probably try to walk this recursively through a tree structure (which is what this is).
However, you're going to run into a couple of problems really quick;

1. A view generally has the effect of *hiding* the implementation details from somebody who wants data from it.  When your application code queries a view for data, it has **no** way to tell that no such table exists - from it's standpoint, the view *is* a base level table.  For a number of reasons, this is *usually* the **desired** outcome (it's the database version of encapsulation).  So unless your java code has access to the view creation scripts (or can somehow get the definition of the views), you will not be able to 'walk' the structure.
2. Aggregate functions are a potential source of trouble.  You're going to have issues with any `CASE` statements that switch fields for evaluation.  You haven't listed your RDBMS, but some of them support multiple columns in some aggregates (like DB2 does for `MAX()`).  This is going to cause problems because your destination column is dependent *on the data retrieved*.
3. Any stored procedures have the potential to completely invalidate your results.  It's perfectly valid for me to create a stored procedure that changes the *tables* it access based on the time of day (depending on use case, this might actually be *necessary*).  Additionally, unless you have the source code, you may not be able to complete the walk.
4. There is a command set called `Alias`, which basically repoints where a table (or view reference) actually points.  This will have the effect of changing what 'base' table you're looking at (from an SQL standpoint).  Depending on how you're getting your data, your Java code may resolve the alias or not.  In either case, an alias is usually temporary, which has the potential to 'expire' your results.

So, in short, for anything like a real-world scenario, it's pretty much impossible...

---

5.How are you planning on handling recursive CTEs (I'm assuming teradata allows them)?  This is something of a wierd subset of point 2; any fields in them either resolves to a 'base table' (what the optimizer sees as a table anyways), or a recursion towards the base table.  You would need to design your program to detect recursion of this type, and deal with it appropriately.  Unfortunately, you won't be able to rely on the terminating condition (evaluated per-line at runtime); thankfully, however, you won't have to deal with cyclical relationships.

Comment: The RDBMS i'm using is teradata and i can do a show on the view and get the view definition with all syntax and everything like that. I was thinking of putting it into a tree structure based off of blocks of data. IE any derived tables or such and then from there doing more processing on the case statements or sum's.

Comment: _How_ are you doing a 'show' on the view - is this through java?  That solves point 1; what about the others?  And _why_ do you want this?  This may be completely impossible for your intended use.

Comment: yes i just run query "show view view_name" and i get the definition from it as a string. Basically the whole point is to show the source that the field comes from whether it be a table or a calculation or whatever

Comment: Okay, that gets you the source for a view.  What happens if you try to supply it with a table name - how do you tell it that something is a bottom level element?  And what do you want to happen in regard to the other points?  Especially in the case of stored procedures, where you do not have control over how it decides source/returns data?

Comment: i know when i hit the bottom level because of the specific db and how my architecture is designed. The other points i can determine from Sql reserved words for teradata. Procedures and functions must have a left and right paran and are not reserved words. So anything that is not a reserved word must be either a function or procedure or table/field name. If it has paran it than must be a function or procedure. in which case i can do a show on that and get the data as well.

Comment: If by 'architecture' you mean 'naming convention', I wouldn't rely on that.  Point 2 can possibly be overcome - if you don't mind getting back a list of fields that won't _always_ apply.  I'm not sure how `show view` would respond to something that has an alias, so 4 could bite you real hard.  Point 3 is the worst; likely (as most other major RDBMS) teradata allows DBAs to code SPs/UDFs in _multiple_ languages - with a different version per library.  Depending on the SP, it might be building queries **dynamically** as well.  Good luck...  Oh, and I can add extra parenthesis wherever I want.